# Why I cannot inherit LinkedListNode<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, linked-list

In .NET 3.5, I am using the LinkedList class but I am having the following issue. I want the items of that list to be aware of the previous and next items in the list. In other words, I want the method in the items to be able to do this.Next, this.Previous. Is this possible? Below is an example of what I would like to do.

```
Day d1 = new Day();
Day d2 = new Day();
LinkedList<Day> days = new LinkedList<Day>();
days.AddLast(d1);
days.AddLast(d2);

// Here is want I would like to do
d1.Next = ...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

First, [`LinkedListNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahf4c754.aspx) is [`sealed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx) so it can not be inherited.

Secondly, `LinkedListNode` does contain properties [`Previous`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de80z2x6.aspx) and [`Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4t9w6be.aspx) that refer to the previous and next nodes in the `LinkedList` that a given instance of `LinkedListNode` came from.

Lastly, to use `AddLast` correctly, you must do the following:

```
Day d1 = new Day();
Day d2 = new Day();
LinkedList<Day> days = new LinkedList<Day>();
LinkedListNode<Day> node1 = days.AddLast(d1);
LinkedListNode<Day> node2 = days.AddLast(d2);

// now node1.Next refers to node containing d2
// and node2.Previous referes to node containing d1
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using it wrong.

The `.AddLast(T)` method returns a linked list node.  This points to your day and has the prev and next functions you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahf4c754.aspx), the LinkedListNode class cannot be inherited.

[Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67132/michael) points out that [this blog post from Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2004/01/22/61803.aspx) talks about why many classes in the framework are sealed

Comment: I know that... but if I could it would help me a lot!

Comment: I just assumed since the title asked why, I would supply the answer!

Comment: rofl; I'm so torn about whether that's a great or terrible answer!  "Why can't inherit from it?"  "Because you can't inherit from it!".  So accurate yet so unhelpful

Comment: @phsr: Technically, I think your source only confirms the fact, rather than offering a reason why. Though I guess "Because Microsoft don't want you to" is a valid reason.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2004/01/22/61803.aspx explains why most framework classes are sealed.  There actually are good reasons.

Answer (score 0):

```
Day d1 = new Day();
Day d2 = new Day();
LinkedList<Day> days = new LinkedList<Day>();
// Day's instance doesn't have Next. Its the LinkedListNode that should be used.
LinkedListNode<Day> d1Node = days.AddLast(d1); 
days.AddLast(d2);
```

Comment: -1. `LinkedListNode<T>.Next` is read-only. You cannot assign to it.

Comment: @dtb: I am sorry. I just took the code from OP's question and corrected the lines which I thought were wrong. I didn't look into whether one can assign to the Next property.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the nodes directly to begin with...

```
LinkedListNode<Day> d1 = new LinkedListNode<Day>(new Day());
LinkedListNode<Day> d2 = new LinkedListNode<Day>(new Day());
LinkedList<Day> days = new LinkedList<Day>();
days.AddLast(d1); 
days.AddLast(d2);

// Now you can read the node directly
d1.Next...

// If you need to place it somewhere other than at the end (like say you want d2 before d1,
// but d1 is already in the list) use 'AddBefore' and 'AddAfter' eg:
days.AddLast(d2);
days.AddBefore(d2, d1);
```

Comment: Oh, should also mention, you now just access "Day" through the 'Value' property of d1/d2

Comment: -1. `LinkedListNode<T>.Next` is read-only. You cannot assign to it.

Comment: Oh, didn't realise that, but you can set it via the AddBefore and AddAfter functions

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to make a generic `T` aware of its siblings is to implement your own data structure.

```
public interface ILinkedListNode
{
    ILinkedListNode Next { get; set; }
    ILinkedListNode Previous { get; set; }
}

public class LinkedList<T> where T : ILinkedListNode 
{
    /*.... methods here ...*/
}

public class Node : ILinkedListNode
{
    public Node Next { get; set; }

    public Node Previous { get; set; }

    ILinkedListNode ILinkedListNode.Next
    {
        get { return this.Next; }
        set { this.Next = (Node)value; }
    }

    ILinkedListNode ILinkedListNode.Previous
    {
        get { return this.Previous; }
        set { this.Previous = (Node)value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

LinkedListNode is a sealed class so it cannot be inherited. We get so spoiled by IEnumerable that we lose sight of the actual data structures we're using. It's still a linked list, so you can treat it like one:

```
LinkedListNode<Day> node = days.First();
while (node != null)
{
    Day day = node.Value;

    // do stuff here...

    node = node.Next();
}
```

Comment: -1 Doing this you will skip the last node as "days.Last" refers to a valid node. The while loop should be "while (node != null)" to get all of the nodes

Comment: Thanks for the correction, but a mistake in the loop doesn't change the fundamental answer: traverse the nodes as you would a doubly-linked list to solve the problem.